# VueJS multiple pages in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following folder structure:

- public

  - index.html
  - login.html
- src

  - components (containing Login.vue)
  - views
  - App.vue
  - main.js

The index.html has the following snippet:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

The login.html has the following snippet:

```
<div id="login"></div>
```

In main.js, I have the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import './components'
import './plugins'
import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync'
import App from './App'
import router from '@/router'
import store from '@/store' 
import Login from './components/Login'

sync(store, router)

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')

new Vue({
   router,
   store,
   render: h => h(Login) ===> I've tried here also "template: Login" and el: '#login' instead of 'mount' but to no avail
}).$mount('#login')
```

While this works for index.html, it does not load for login.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was made by adding extra pages in `vue.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
pages: {
    index: {
        entry: 'src/main.js',
        template: 'public/index.html',
        filename: 'index.html',
        title: 'Index Page',
    },
    login: {
        entry: 'src/main.js',
        template: 'public/login.html',
        filename: 'login.html',
    },
    register: {
        entry: 'src/main.js',
        template: 'public/register.html',
        filename: 'register.html',
    },
},
devServer: {
   disableHostCheck: true
}
```

}